# PHP convert columns to query

Tags: php

I have a table on the frontend, where the user can choose what types of columns he wants.
After submitting the form I get the array with selected columns.
For instance the user select following columns:

```php
$columns = ["campaign_start_time", "campiagn_end_time", "campaign_id", "campaign_budget", "adset_name", "ad_name"]
```

Now I have to make the request to the facebook api, but facebook api only request query in form:

```
 $query = "campaign{start_time, end_time, id, budget}, adset{name}, ad{name}"
```

Here is my question, what is the best way to convert **$columns** to **$query** in PHP language?

Comment: You should change the form to submit the columns in a way that is easier to work with on the backend.

Comment: So how they should look like?

Comment: You haven't shown your form but inputs or whatever fields you submit would have names like `name="campaign[start_time]"`  `name="campaign[end_time]"` or something.  Or  `name="campaign[] value="start_time"` whatever.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

If you can construct your submitted data to be in this form:

```
Array
(
    [campaign] => Array
        (
            [0] => start_time
            [1] => end_time
            [2] => id
            [3] => budget
        )
    [adset] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
        )
    [ad] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
        )
)
```

Maybe using inputs or other constructs such as:

```
name="campaign[]" value="start_time"
name="campaign[]" value="end_time"
```

Then looping and building the query with the keys and values will do it:

```
foreach($columns as $key => $val) {
    $query[] = $key . '{' . implode(',', $val) . '}';
}
$query = implode(',', $query);
```

Otherwise you'll need to parse it to get what you need first, then execute the loop above using `$result` instead:

```
foreach($columns as $val) {
    preg_match('/^([^_]+)_(.*)/', $val, $match);
    $result[$match[1]][] = $match[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution splits apart the values based on underscores and then joins them back together as nested values based on the category/key. Note that this doesn't check for items that don't have a "prefix".

```
<?php
$columns = ["campaign_start_time", "campaign_end_time", "campaign_id", "campaign_budget", "adset_name", "ad_name"];

$criteria = [];
foreach( $columns as $column ){
    $pieces = explode('_',$column);
    $category = array_shift($pieces);
    
    if( !isset($criteria[$category]) ){
        $criteria[$category] = [];
    }
    
    $criteria[$category][] = implode('_', $pieces);
}

$queryPieces = [];
foreach($criteria as $category => $values){
    $queryPieces[] = $category.'{'.implode(', ', $values).'}';
}

$query = implode(', ', $queryPieces);
```